# List processing in DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have of List of words as a DStream. Eg: List(car, speed, accident, speed, bad). I want to form bi grams from this list. I have this with RDDs but facing issues with DStreams. I am using the foreachRDD function. Below is what I have -

Am trying to print the contents of RDD after transformation.

```
 def printRDD(rddString: RDD[String]) ={
      val z = rddString.map( y => y.toString.split(",").filter(_.nonEmpty).
        map( y => y.replaceAll("""\W""", "").toLowerCase)
        .filter(_.nonEmpty)
        .sliding(2).filter(_.size == 2).map{ case Array(a, b) => ((a, b), 1) })
        .flatMap(x => x)
        println(z)
}
 val x = lines.map(plainTextToLemmas(_, stopWords))
 val words = x.flatMap( y=> y.toString.split(","))
 words.foreachRDD( rdd => printRDD(rdd))
```

Is there any way to show the contents after transformation function printRDD. Even if I use println(z) inside the print definition, it returns MapPartitionsRDD[18] at flatMap. I am using Kafka spark streaming to read inputs, I get the words value on the console. I think the words do not get changed after invoking the function printRDD.

Comment: what should happen to the bigrams after the stream processing? That function just do console printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all these operating on the `DStream`, not inside `foreachRDD` and then call `print` on the `DStream`:

```
lines
  .map(plainTextToLemmas(_, stopWords))
  .flatMap(y => y.toString.split(","))
  .map(y => y.toString.split(",").filter(_.nonEmpty))
  .map(y => y.replaceAll("""\W""", "").toLowerCase)
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .sliding(2)
  .filter(_.size == 2)
  .flatMap { case Array(a, b) => ((a, b), 1) } 
  .print()
```

This should print out the content of the `DStream` to the console on the Driver.

An important thing to note is that although you're operating on a `DStream`, it's methods "drill into" the underlying `RDD` at the given batch time and expose the actual type inside the `RDD`, so you shouldn't need to use `foreachRDD` to reach the actual data inside.